# Make decorator for singelton class -- typescript

Tags: typescript, decorator

I am building a project using VueJS with Typescript. I feel comfortable using services instead of any state management library like Vuex. But when writing services I have to always copy paste some code in each service class, to make it singelton as:

```
class MyService {
  private static Instance: MyService;
  public static getInstance() {
    if (!MyService.Instance) {
      MyService.Instance = new MyService();
    }
    return MyService.Instance;
  }
  private constructor() {}
}
```

I was thinking about the decorators, so my question is can we really get rid of this above code and use decorator, I tried some failed attempts as:

```
function service<T>(): T {
  const Instance: T | null = null;
  return !Instance ? new T() : Instance;
}

@service<MyService>()
```

or

```
function service(constructor: Function) {
  const Instance: MyService | null = null;
  return !Instance ? new MyService() : Instance;
}
@service
```

but these are not going to work. I am not sure that decorator will do the trick or not, other method may work here, but I don't have any idea, any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have the answer but i love the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you can try as follow

singletone.decorator.ts

```
const serviceList: any[] = [];

export function AsSingletone() {
    return (target: any): void  => {
        if(target.prototype.Instance) {
            return;
        }
        serviceList.push(target);
        Object.defineProperty(target, 'Instance', {
            get: function () {
                if (target.prototype.Instance) {
                    return target.prototype.Instance;
                }
                const instance = new target();
                target.prototype.Instance = instance;
                Object.defineProperty(target, 'Instance',
                  { get: function () { return instance; } }
                );
                return instance;
            }, configurable: true
        });
    };
}

export function registeredServiceList(): any[] {
    return serviceList;
}
```

service.ts

```
import { AsSingletone } from "./singletone.decorator";

@AsSingletone()
export class MyService {
  public static readonly Instance: MyService;
}
```

get access

```
console.log(MyService.Instance);
```

set throws exception

```
MyService.Instance = (new MyService() as any).Instance as MyService;
```

[typescript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=56&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmAnAbgS2PAMq6AuGAhmAJ4DaAujALwwUDcAUAwGYCuYwUq4MAghAGVUYAOYAbeFHDwAFAEoYAbwYxVMRJNaIwMGVAKIRk-EWJz8yEKgAmqqgD4lKtS9TM9Bo1AB0AB0QgUlDEvvDeAJKQ+hzwCsouCWoaUFpgjImqAL7OiQgo6Fg4Pr6sEAAWHoaScukZAPIARgBW8Jze1vDMwvAACgGhiMGVXgA0MADkkdBEGONj8RkuXvhsHFw88k6Li266+lXFAUEhYVPRGHE524vJqTD7Xn5HgScRUTPwtdcu2d8JoFEYMJpjFqDAwPAAO73TySeRfP4wg5PQIvUJvEEYMHA86fK5-RotNodLoQvogAZDB6SMaTd4xOZKGDLGCrTjcHSbRTqTTaIH0jB0GCZYU1fHfW58nEfBGLTJjAFdERaAgNCT4KCIVjwcVZMU-RjZBgAAX4QlEEikEPkDGAYgIEAgMAAssQBEg0FiFqoSmr0HB9FxgDAzh98K73flBQwjXaHU6Ix6CgAmLZqfyoZAEKDwAPZ-2hmLht1JjDJhG+sT+6ZB5mSQsYLm6oHMXQAQkTUfgyYxuMu107nu7vY+YIh0MHKfhzd+GUlOknZZHMQRs59iEz2dzAOgWs4IEQXOysfAEBAEm8YhAIhki9OAtijAYlvuqAAtkgwQBaAbMA9vj5vDAEBIWnF8czfXwwXYElumsRg-0PF9UCoAAGOhUAAHgARlQvD8PQ1AAGoiP7e54EgsE72XaNsi4D9EBgIiaF-f9AOA0CxR3c8wivG8ACIABV33gfB+KYvYRMQAB6XC8LkbwpAAMVQAAPeBrBkABWBQiJgcSEGAbx+LkJh6M-GgfyQRCAJiICQOnRCZGQtCMJwgj8IwkiyNUCCoJoO8ey8BtZDFOipKYljrLYuyOOnbiLz4mQhJEsSJL0KTZPwhTlLUjTtN0-S4FaYzTIYIA)

VS Code snippet template, start typing - singl

```
"Singletone": {
    "prefix": ["singl"],
    "body": [
        "AsSingletone()\r",
        "export class ${0}Service {\r",
        "\tpublic static readonly Instance: ${0}Service;",
        "}"],
    "description": "Singletone service template"
  }
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `registeredServiceList`??

Comment: And what's your opinion will it be good performance wise or not? is this better in performance than using mine code?

Comment: registeredServiceList if you need get all singletons for debug in example

Comment: @user12061795 defineProperty usually optimized and work in same speed, but implementation without if() works faster. i add link to playground with some tests

Comment: there's an issue with it, when the code it going to compile by webpack, all the classes having this decorator will be initialized, which is not a good thing, any suggestion on it?

Comment: @user12061795 at which moment you like to initialize it?

Comment: I am using VueJS for SPA, so if i am not visiting any specific route, then the service should not be initialized, as my project have ton of services, i can't load all of them. I am having component files in which I am using it, so if the component is not initialized then the services shouldn't too.

Comment: @user12061795 i update decorator it will initialize on first call of MyService.Instance

Comment: Now it means the class is not going to init untill unless I call the getter as `MyService.Instance`, right?

Comment: One more question as you have added Instance using `defineProperty` then why again adding to `.prototype`??, I removed the prototype line and checked directly as `target.Instance` and it worked.

Comment: @user12061795 yes first call to MyService.Instance will init property

Comment: @user12061795 on decorator start defineProperty just preparing for the first call to property, after in first call we no need anymore all preparation code and with second defineProperty we just make it return 'instance' object without additional if()

Comment: I know about that i am asking about why adding to **.prototype**.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and all the efforts you put, thanks man! You made my day and i really hope you got your day bright and lighten up, i am thankful to you from my heart, thanks again, (followed you on GitHub, stared your repos), just can't explain how happy I'm, you are great :) :) :)

Comment: in case we need iterate all decorated types it is better have target.prototype.Instance, because MyService.Instance overridden, but definitely it looks redundant

Comment: Hope you keep getting it, because TypeScript is LOVE :)

Comment: I would like to ask one last question, that i did this decorator thing because i want to get rid of writing `public static Instance: MyService;` + it's getter every where, as you made it happen, and now i have to only write the instance line, but it would be better if we move it to a super class and extends it in all classes, so i tried like `class BaseService<T> {}` but here's a problem that type parameters can't be used on static members, else it works fine, i also tried to solve it, but didn't work, can you make it possible?, or atleast any hint?

Comment: @user12061795 it seems nothing we can do with it. for a new code we can use code snippet template

Answer (score 2):

what about this decorator?

```
export interface ServiceClassOptions {
    isSingleton: boolean;
}

/* eslint-disable space-before-function-paren */
export function ServiceClass(options: ServiceClassOptions) {
    return (constructor: any) => {
        console.log('from decorator', constructor.prototype.Instance);
        const original = constructor;

        const fun: any = (...args) => {
            if (options.isSingleton) {
                if (constructor.prototype.Instance) {
                    return constructor.prototype.Instance;
                } else {
                    const instance = new constructor(...args);
                    constructor.prototype.Instance = instance;

                    return instance;
                }
            }
            return new constructor(...args);
        };

        fun.prototype = original.prototype;

        return fun;
    };
}
```

decorator class as follows

```
@ServiceClass({
    isSingleton: true
})
export class AnyService {
}
```

then call `new AnyService();` anytime you want will return same instance if `isSingleton = true`