# Annotate a class using declaration file? -- TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a decorator which adds a property into the class as:

```
function Service(constructor: any): any {
  constructor.Instance = {};
}

@Service
class MyService {

}
```

The property will be `static` as `public static Instance: MyService`, but i have a bunch of classes, i just can't add `public static Instance: ServiceType`, in every class. What I did is:

```
class BaseService<T> {
  public static Instance: T; // Static members cannot reference class type parameters.ts(2302)
}

@Service
class MyService extends BaseService<MyService> {

}
```

Which should work but I got `Static members cannot reference class type parameters.ts(2302)`, so i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52519934/12061795) as:

```
function BaseService<T>() {
  abstract class BaseService {
    public static Instance: T;
  }
  return BaseService;
}

@Service
class MyService extends BaseService<MyService> { // Type '<T>() => typeof BaseService' is not a constructor function type.ts(2507)

}
```

this also not worked, so i think can we make a declaration file, in which we can declare `BaseService` class as a type, but I am confused how to use that type? `implements? extends?`, but Type can't be extended or implemented. As the `Instance` already exists in the class, what i need exactly is to annotate the class with that property, so that i can access it like `MyService.Instance`, and i don't want to add explicitly in all classes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have choosen an other way of doing it, here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61645814/12061795). In short the decorator functionality I was doing is a bit difficult, but now I have got an other way of doing it, so it solves my question.